# Building tree node structure - parents show first - and `path` prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Im getting an array looks like this:

```
const nodes = [
  { id: 1, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 5, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 7, parentId: 4 },
  { id: 8, parentId: 7 },
  { id: 9, parentId: 8 },
];
```

Each node contain id  and parentId props. parentId will point node id.
For example `{id: 1, parentId: 3}`, `{id:2, parentId:1}`,`{id:3}` means the the root is ,`{id:3}` and he has one child which is `{id: 1, parentId: 3}`, and he has one child of his own which is  `{id:2, parentId:1}` this one doesn’t have children.

I want to sort the array in a way that parents always shows before their children, no option to this to happen: `[{id: 1, parentId: 3}, {id:2, parentId:1}, {id:3}]` the right order is `[{id:3},{id: 1, parentId: 3}, {id:2, parentId:1}]`. if a node has a multiple children (order of the children is not important as long as their parent will come before them).

In addition, I want to add each node a prop called `path` it needs to indicate nodes parents id + node.id and provide the path to the node.

For example for this node:
{ id: 6, parentId: 1 } path should look like this: { id: 6, parentId: 1, path: 1/6 }.
for this node { id: 7, parentId: 4 } path should look like this { id: 7, parentId: 4, path: 3/4/7 }.

This is my function:

```
const sortAndNormalizeTree = (
collections: Collection[],
    ): CollectionRawNode[] => {
    // Create a Map to store nodes based on their IDs
       const nodeMap = new Map();

 collections.forEach(node => {
   nodeMap.set(node.id, node);
 });

 // Perform depth-first search (post-order) to build the sorted array
 const sortedNodes: CollectionRawNode[] = [];
 const visited = new Set();

const dfs = (node: Collection) => {
  if (!visited.has(node.id)) {
    visited.set(node.id);

  if (node.parentId && nodeMap.has(node.parentId)) {
    const parentNode = nodeMap.get(node.parentId);
    dfs(parentNode);
  }

  // Update the path for the current node after processing its children
  node.path = node.parentId
    ? `${nodeMap.get(node.parentId).path}/${node.id}`
    : `${node.id}`;

  sortedNodes.push({
    isFolder: true,
    type: EntityType.collection,
    name: node.name,
    id: node.id,
    path: node.path,
  });
 }
 };

 collections.forEach(node => {
   dfs(node);
 });

 return sortedNodes;
};
```

This function works. I dont want to use it, I want other suggestions (more optimized)
Maybe using tail recursion optimization.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could basically create a nested tree first using recursion, where you also keep track of paths. And after that you flatten it by traversing over the tree you just built and keep the nested order.

```js
const nodes = [
  { id: 1, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 5, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 7, parentId: 4 },
  { id: 8, parentId: 7 },
  { id: 9, parentId: 8 },
];

function buildTree(data, parentId = undefined, path = '') {
  return nodes.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (e.parentId == parentId) {
      const obj = { ...e }
      obj.path = (path + (path.length ? '/' : '') + e.id)
      obj.children = [...buildTree(data, obj.id, obj.path)]

      r.push(obj)
    }

    return r
  }, [])
}

function flattenData(data) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    const { children, ...rest } = e;

    r.push(rest)

    if (children) {
      r.push(...flattenData(children))
    }

    return r
  }, [])
}

const tree = buildTree(nodes)
const result = flattenData(tree)

console.log(tree)
console.log(result)
```